# Formatting string in relplot subplot title

Tags: string, seaborn, subplot

Please note this is an edited version of my previous post.

I am trying to format the title of subplots generated using relplot in Seaborn. I am using the set_titles option and am including the {col_name} element. I would like to precede {col_name} with a dynamic string from the array of formatted strings "plotvarnames" (e.g., "I_{bs}=")  before {col_name}. The following lines of code results in the error message "name 'col_name' is not defined":

```
plotvars=['nis','Ds','Ibs','kVssH','kVssL','kHL']
plotvarstrings=["r'$\nu_s$'","r'$D_s$'","r'$I_{bs}$'","r'$k_{vSSH}$'","r'$k_{vSSL}$'","r'$k_{HL}$'"]
for i,vname in enumerate (plotvars):   g=sns.relplot(x="xvar",y="yvar",col=vname,hue="huevar",col_wrap=3,kind="scatter",palette=["b","r"],data=df,legend="full").set_titles(f"plotvarstrings[i]={col_name}")
```

How can I obtain the composed, formatted string?

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is not working. I am getting the error message "name 'bs' is not defined".

Comment: Hi, {col_name} is the template for plotting the value taken by the column variable {col_var} in the set_titles command for relplot (see e.g. https://kite.com/python/docs/seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid.set_titles).

Comment: Thanks, I read up on this and posted an answer. Let me know how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I figured it out: you need to escape the brackets. Change `plotvarstrings` to the below (note the double `{{` and `}}`:

```
plotvarstrings=['r[$\nu_s$]','r[$D_s$]','r'$I_{{bs}}$]','r[$k_{{vSSH}}$]',
                'r[$k_{{vSSL}}$]','r[$k_{{HL}}$]']
```

Then you can do this:

```
.set_titles(plotvarstrings[i] + "={col_name}")
```

Comment: Your suggestion works in terms of the routine not crashing for the first two elements in plotvarstrings, but in all cases I am unable to format the raw strings. For instance, I have tried defining the plotvarstrings array both as plotvarstrings=["r'$\nu_s$'","r'$D_s$'","r'$I_{bs}$'","r'$k_{vSSH}$'","r'$k_{vSSL}$'","r'$k_{HL}$'"] and plotvarstrings=['r[$\nu_s$]','r[$D_s$]','r'$I_{bs}$]','r[$k_{vSSH}$]','r[$k_{vSSL}$]','r[$k_{HL}$]'] but I do not get the properly formatted strings. Moreover, the routine crashes when I get to the string I_{bs} as I get the error message "KeyError: 'bs'".

Comment: @Woland72: I just figured out what was wrong. Apologies that it took me a while. Please see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time; works beautifully now.